# How can we use read_excel for reading .xlsx files in R?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, xlsx, purrr

I want to read all the Excel files one by one to temp.data variable. Is there a way to do it? I tried this

```
for (i in 1:15) {
temp.data <- read_excel(file.path("../source",files$file_path[[i]]))
}
```

Or is there an alternative way for NOT using for loop here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You store all of them in the same variable, so override previous file with new file. You should store the data in a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the ouptut in a data frame and you have relevant files in the "source" folder, the following should do:

```
purrr::map_dfr(list.files("../source", full.names = TRUE), read_excel)
```

If you have only specific files included in a vector as it appears from your code, this may serve you well:

```
purrr::map_dfr(file.path("../source",files$file_path), read_excel)
```

Comment: where should i keep  files$file_path[[i]]) in
 ```purrr::map_dfr(list.files("../source", full.names = TRUE), read_excel)```  @giocomai

Comment: that line of code assumes you have all files in that "source" folder... if you have a list of files in a vector, then you can put that vector instead of `list.files("../source", full.names = TRUE)` (without the [i] that comes from the loop... there's no loop here)

Answer (score 1):

To store the resulting `data.frame`s in a list you can do:

```
lapply(file.path("../source", files$file_path), read_excel)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use de `map` function from the `purrr` package:

```
your_path = "C:\...\2_souce_data"
files_xlsx <- list.files(your_path, pattern = ".xlsx", full.names = T)

temp.data = map(files_xlsx, read_excel, sheet = "your_sheet_index_or_name", col_names =TRUE)
```